# Must declare scalar variable when binding aspgridview to aspsqldatasource

Tags: asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I'm having difficulties in understanding how parameters in aspsqldatasource know where to get their values. Here is an example:
My users table is as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE HR.Users
(
userid CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
passwordhash BINARY(64) NOT NULL,
firstname NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
lastname NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
sex NCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
divisionid TINYINT NOT NULL,
mandatoryworkingdays VARCHAR(6),
superiorinunitid CHAR(3),
managerid CHAR(3),
privilage NVARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
salt UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
active BIT CONSTRAINT DFT_Active DEFAULT(1),
DateKey INT NOT NULL,
availablevacations INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DFT_NumberOfVacations DEFAULT(880),
vacationlastupdatemonth VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DFT_VacationUpdateMonth DEFAULT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),  CONVERT([dbo].[PersianDate], dbo.[UDF_Gregorian_To_Persian](GETDATE())).Month)),
ishourly BIT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DFT_Hourly DEFAULT(1),
CONSTRAINT PK_Users PRIMARY KEY(userid),
CONSTRAINT FK_Users_Devisions FOREIGN KEY(divisionid) REFERENCES HR.Divisions(divisionid),
CONSTRAINT FK_Users_Date FOREIGN KEY(DateKey) REFERENCES dbo.DimDate(DateKey)
);
```

I bind it to aspgridview using aspsqldatasource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourcePSM" runat="server"
SelectCommand="id, name, unit, startdate, remaining, superid, managerid, [ishourly] FROM [PSM].[HR].[ShowUsers]"
DeleteCommand="UPDATE HR.Users SET active=0 WHERE [userid] = @id"
UpdateCommand="UPDATE HR.Users SET [managerid] = @managerid, [superiorinunitid] = @superid, [ishourly] = @ishourly  WHERE [userid] = @id">
<DeleteParameters>
<asp:Parameter Name="@id" Type="Char" />
</DeleteParameters>
<UpdateParameters>
<asp:Parameter Name="@id" Type="Char" />
<asp:Parameter Name="@superid" Type="Char" />
<asp:Parameter Name="@managerid" Type="Char" />
<asp:Parameter Name="@ishourly" Type="Byte"  DefaultValue="0"/>
</UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

When updating aspsqldatasource using aspgridview I receive

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Must declare the scalar variable
>   "@id"

error.